# awk range and selection of text

Tags: awk

I know how to use the range operator in awk

```
awk '/start/,/stop/' file
```

Is it possible to select text inside the range operator? ATM, I am using an if statement

```
awk '/start/,/stop/ { if ($1~/foo/) { } }' file
```

is there a more idomatic way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use a range expression as it makes trivial jobs very slightly briefer but then requires a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when the task gets slightly more interesting.

Instead of:

```
awk '/start/,/stop/' file
```

Use:

```
awk '/start/{f=1} f{print} /stop/{f=0}' file
```

and then what you want to do becomes simply:

```
awk '/start/{f=1} f{ if ($1~/foo/) { } } /stop/{f=0}' file
```

I'm assuming you have something in mind for inside the empty `{ }`.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you have proposed does work:

```
$ seq 1 15 | awk '/^6/,/^9/ { if ($1~/8/){print} else print "in range but not 8" }'
in range but not 8
in range but not 8
8
in range but not 8
```

But as Ed Morton states, it is a brittle construct.

Example, the `,` is the lowest precedence and you may scratch your head over why this does not work:

```
$ echo "this one print" | awk '/^1/ , /^55/ || /this/'
```

Another example. Suppose you have:

```
$ echo "a
b
c
---
d
e
f
---
g
h"
```

Try and use a range operator to include or exclude everything between `---`. It is [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15955111/298607) since the start and end marks are the same and it is possible to [set and reset](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) a range on the same line.

When if you train you muscle memory to not do `/^x/ , /^y/` and instead do `/^x/{flag=1} flag{whatever} /^y/{flag=0}` then no more head scratching:

```
$ echo "this one print" | awk '/^1/{flag=1} flag || /this/{print} /^55/{flag=0}'
this one print
```

Or,

```
$ echo "a
b
c
---
d
e
f
---
g
h" | awk '/^---$/{f= ! f; next}  f'
d
e
f
```

(Just change to `! f` at the end if you want to reverse from include to exclude...)

So in general, you can do this for a range and subrange:

```
awk '/^start/ || /^end/{f= ! f; next} /e/ && f { what you do in sub range }' file

         ^         ^                            can be a single regex if same pattern
                                 ^              remove next to include in processing
                                      ^         applies to within range /start/,/end/
                                          ^  ^     because of the flag
```