# awk all lines between two words in one file with multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I am trying to get all lines in some SQL code between WHERE and GROUP, I have the below, which gets me the first occurrence of text between WHERE and GROUP, but there are multiple occurrences of the same I am after

`awk '/WHERE/{p=1} p; /GROUP/{exit}' filename.txt`

Output

`WHERE something
Some SQL code
GROUP BY something`

There are multiple sections of the code that start with WHERE and end with GROUP BY with in the file I would like to output

Can anybody help?

Comment: try resetting `p` to `0` where you are past the `GROUP` condition.

Comment: I'm curious - what do you think your posed code means? If you know what it means then it's utterly trivial to change to do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awk range and selection of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982874/awk-range-and-selection-of-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better in `awk` to do something along these lines:

```
awk '/WHERE/{f=1} f; /GROUP/{f=0}' file
```

The `awk` range operator `,`  works similarly to `sed`. However, it is difficult to modify and you limit what awk can do.

Once your awk habit includes using a flag (rather than a range) it will be easier to print between marks such as:

```
$ echo "a
b
c
---
d
e
f
---
g
h" | awk '/^---$/{f= ! f; next}  f'
d
e
f
```

Which is impossible with the range operator.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/WHERE/,/GROUP/' filename.txt
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).